# Switch Browser to "sleep mode" (disabled) and switch back

Tags: java, opengl, jxbrowser

I am trying to embed a website as a user interface into a game I'm making using **JxBrowser**. The problem is, keeping the browser running in the background causes the game's FPS drops from 120 to 20.

Since I need to render the BufferedImage from the browser, I don't think I can switch to HeavyWeight mode for that GPU-acceleration (Please correct me if I can).

The plan is, the browser is only active under certain circumstances (e.g. player is looking at the interface). **I wonder if there's any way that I can disable the browser, and resume to previous state when needed?**

P.S. I do notice the browser.dispose() method, but that won't resume the browser to the previous state before disabled.

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser doesn't provide any API to "disable" the browser.

JxBrowser uses CPU to perform the off-screen rendering in the lightweight mode. Every time something changes on the loaded document(e.g. DOM updates, etc.) JxBrowser re-renders the web page content in memory.
Probably, this is the root-cause of the FPS decreasing.

I suggest that you find the way to display more statical content in the user interface.

Also, please take a look at the following article, maybe an accelerated rendering helps reduce this issue:
https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000104965-accelerated-lightweight-rendering